# What is news/analytics site to read about StarCraft2

Tags: starcraft-2

I am trying to find web sites that contain articles, game/tournament descriptions, events regarding to StarCraft2. Among others, what I am interested in is something like "you tube replay", but made not in video, but in text-form.

I know we can read something on team liquid forum, but that is more like a forum, with question and strategies, sometime theory-crafting, some time with replays/videos...

P.S. The reason why I don't like video-replays is that I want to do that sometime in work-time, but we don't have a bandwidth issues..

Thanks.

Comment: Have yo u looked at any of the team liquid blogs? Or weekly recaps? Those sound like exactly what you want.

Comment: Is there any way to convert this question to a wili?

Comment: do you think that you need the community to collaborate to edit this question?

Comment: tzenes would actually do it single-handedly :)

Answer (score 1):

http://rpg-exploiters.com/category/starcraft-series/ - contains a often to populate articles, among others:

- best-counters for TvT: http://rpg-exploiters.com/guides-strategies/sc2-terran-strategy-best-counters-vs-terran-units/,
- counters in general: http://rpg-exploiters.com/category/starcraft-series/counter-starcraft-series/

Answer (score 0):

I think that [www.teamliquid.net](http://www.teamliquid.net) has everything:

- SC2 streams
- The TeamLiquid Star league
- Builds

and so on.